# Create JAXBElement<Book> from String

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a class Book defined and I want to create a JAXBElement object that will contain the information corresponding to the XML from the String object.

For example, I can have something like:

```
String code = "<book><title>Harry Potter</title></book>";
```

Now, I want to create a JAXBElement, starting from that string. I need the string to do some validations that I cannot do using JAXBElement.

So, can I do what I want? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Sorin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use one of the `unmarshal` methods that takes a `Class` parameter you will receive an instance of `JAXBElement`.

**Demo**

```
package forum13709611;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Book.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        String code = "<book><title>Harry Potter</title></book>";
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(code));
        JAXBElement<Book> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Book.class);
    }

}
```

**Book**

```
package forum13709611;

public class Book {

    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```